# Segfault with stringstream

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault

This is my function:

```
string GaugeStr;
void someFunction() {
    float pie = someFloat();
    stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << pie;
    GaugeStr = ss.str();
}
```

When I run the function, it works properly. When I call it however for a second time (`someFunction(); someFunction();`, then my program crashes with a segmentation fault.

I tried putting `stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);` out of the function to make it a global variable, but the contents I want to send to `GaugeStr` get appended to `ss`. For example, if we assume that `someFloat()` always returns 1.2, then the second time I run the function, `GaugeStr` is set to `1.21.2`.

So, I inserted `ss.str("")` in the function, but the program crashes again with a segfault.

What can I do to put the value of `someFloat()` is `GaugeStr` as a string without a segfault?

### Exact Function

```
void CPU_BenchmarkFrame::OnButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event) {
    float pie = PiAlgo (Gauge2);
    stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << pie;
    wxMessageBox(_("Alert"), _("Sample Alert")); //To test where the segfault happens
    string GaugeStr = ss.str();

    wstring GaugeWid;
    std::copy(GaugeStr.begin(), GaugeStr.end(), GaugeWid.begin());

    StaticText2->SetLabel(GaugeWid);
}
```

#### Even more edits

The problem is one or more lines here:

```
    wstring GaugeWid;
    std::copy(GaugeStr.begin(), GaugeStr.end(), GaugeWid.begin());

    StaticText2->SetLabel(GaugeWid);
```

when I commented them the script worked normally.

Comment: can you post a piece of complete code with `main()` that causes seg fault?

Comment: This looks ok. There problem is in the code you didn't show.

Comment: What is the exact origin of the seg fault? A stack trace would be nice...

Comment: @Donotalo In fact, I'm working on a project with wxwidgets in Code::Blocks. And yes, it is for some reason working on its own.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but your constructor argument is redundant – leave it off (`in | out` is already the default value).

Comment: I tried to reproduce it, but my version works like a charm - so I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: @eran http://pastebin.com/tzkUpAN2

Comment: @kongr A stack trace without debugging symbols and without context is exactly zero use. All this tells us is that the error is … *somewhere* (more precisely, at a location marked `??`). Please provide a minimal working example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: OT: You seem to be making a benchmark. However I see highly inefficient code surrounding it (even a GUI?), that will skew the benchmark results, possibly beyond useful meaning

Comment: @sehe Just for fun. (or so that I can see how slow and old my processor is) And it is 100 times better that one written in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Bo spotted a good line (after the question was edited...). I agree.

Here is a suggestion to fix it:

```
GaugeWid.clear();
std::copy(GaugeStr.begin(), GaugeStr.end(), std::back_inserter(GaugeWid));
```

---

@kongr45gpen:

I suspect a threading bug:

- you are doing updates of a variable names GaugeStr (sounds like meter monitoring)
- the code breaks on innocuous assignment to ....... a global.

**Sounds like a threading bug.** Do you use threads, if so, you must appropriately lock GaugeStr or make it a thread local.

Drop me a note if I need to expand on these, because at current I cannot be sure you are using threading.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work

```
std::wstring GaugeWid;
std::copy(GaugeStr.begin(), GaugeStr.end(), GaugeWid.begin());
```

when `GaugeWid` doesn't have a size. And it doesn't convert the characters either.

If you want a wide string, use a `wstringstream`.

Comment: Exactly. The problem is how I can set one, so the programme can run without segfaults.

Comment: I posted a suggestion in my answer

Answer (score 2):

I just tried it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string GaugeStr;

float someFloat() {  
   return (float) 3.41; 
}

void someFunction() {

    float pie = someFloat();
    stringstream ss (stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    ss << pie;
    GaugeStr = ss.str(); 
}

int main() {    
   someFunction();    
   someFunction();

   return 0; 
}
```

This compiles with gcc-compiler version 4.4.0 (running on Windows, IDE: CodeBlocks).

Comment: And it is [here now (codepad)](http://codepad.org/XUQEyDhx) so you can edit it and watch it run :)

Comment: @sehe I know, I tried it on my own, it works, but it doesn't work in my project.

Comment: @kongr45gpen: Well it is nice to know you know. What was the question again?